# How can I change the Test Explorer's duration timer to be more useful for long (>1 sec) tests?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a series of test cases programmed in Visual Studio 2013 that run through Visual Studio's built-in Test Explorer.  These are not unit tests, so they all run for at least a few seconds.  Due to the nature of what is being tested, some of these tests can even run longer than 60 seconds.

The test explorer seems to be designed with unit tests in mind, so a lot of the features relating to the duration of tests are not useful to me.  If either of the following were possible, it would be beneficial to me:

- Changing the meaning of "Slow," "Medium," and "Fast" tests.  When I sort my tests by duration, all my tests land in the same section.  If I could redefine the speed of a "Fast" or "Medium" test, I could make it so my relatively fast tests are not considered "Slow."
- Keeping Test Explorer from rounding on the duration of tests that last greater than 60 seconds.  "75 seconds" is more useful to me than "1 minute."  If I could keep Test Explorer in seconds, I could better keep my own records as for how long these tests take.

If you could point me in the right direction to changing either of these settings, it would be much appreciated.