# Is there a way to configure what Visual Studio thinks is a fast test?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

By default Visual Studio groups tests as Fast if they take less than 100 ms. Is there a way to change this setting?
In my world a fast test is much faster than 100 ms. Is there a way to configure this?

[image]

Comment: Similar post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805031/how-can-i-change-the-test-explorers-duration-timer-to-be-more-useful-for-long

Comment: Yeah, is it dupe enough for deleting this?

Comment: The linked question doesn't have any answers so this can't be closed as a duplicate. If this question gets answered the other one could be closed as a duplicate of this.

Comment: correct approach would be to make a bounty (draw attention)....